# How to see Table detail when writing query?

Tags: oracle, sybase, oracle-sqldeveloper

**How to see Table detail when writing query?**

Hi, i am new to using Embarcadero DBArtisan for Oracle and Syabase queries executions.
but i am unable to see the tables and fields information when i write queries.

**Forexample:**

```
Databasname.User.Table.Fields
```

Suppose if i write first Database name and write .(dot) it should show me all users and when i pick one user and write .(dot) agian it should show me all tables inside and when i pick one table and write .(dot) it should show me all the fields inside.

But it is not doing that way. every time i have to describe table to find the specific field in  the table.

I am woundering if i have to choose some option to see this information.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sybase, there is no User.
I think you have to write a cursor to loop over the DBs on a server.

For the rest of your question:

```
select db_name() 'databasename', b.name 'table', a.name 'fields'
from syscolumns a, sysobjects b
where a.id = b.id
-- and b.type = 'U' -- User tables only
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a setting in Code Workbench. Please see **page 733** in the [**DBArtisan User Guide**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/dbartisan/dbartisan9.5/DBArtisan_9.5_User_EN.pdf&ei=5hx-U5r9FoqlsQTK7IHwAQ&usg=AFQjCNG_UdZZDWaWBVI7nk_kYzSaiw1fLg&bvm=bv.67229260,d.cWc).

From the Manual,

```
    In the ISQL Window, when Enable Auto Replacement is selected on the Setting Tab, 
the application uses "dot completion" auto population to display the list of columns 
for the target table.
```